# Difference between dynamic memory allocation and automatic allocation of user defined classes in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a class "DMRecSessionObj" which has two integer, a string and a vector as its data members.

```
class DMRecSessionObj
{
private:
    int callNum;
    int totCalls;
    std::string sessionKey;
    std::vector<DMRecord>RecList;
public:
   ...
};
```

After creating an object of DMRecSessionObj, the size of the vector RecList will be around 150000 when data is pushed into it according to requirement.
Several such DMRecSessionObj objects will be stored in a static map.

```
static std::map<string,DMRecSessionObj*> mapExpSessData;
```

So, I would like to know the better option of creating the DMRecSessionObj objects.

```
DMRecSessionObj* dmRec = new DMRecSessionObj(); //Dynamic memory allocation
DMRecSessionObj dmRecSessionObj; //Automatic memory allocation
```

The intention of asking this question is to understand the impacts that need to be taken care of in both these cases.

1. Dynamic Memory Allocation
2. Automatic memory allocation by compiler

Please suggest the better option considering the high memory requirements as the scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you use STL, memory used internally will be created at the heap.

Comment: Fill it with data and then print `sizeof`.

Comment: `DMRecSessionObj dmRecSessionObj();` does not define a variable or perform any "automatic memory allocation".   It is an example of the most vexing parse, and declares a function.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough rule of thumb, if you are using operator `new` directly, you should consider using standard containers (`std::vector`, `std::map`, etc) AND avoid use of raw pointers AND not use operator `new` directly.

As another rough rule of thumb, if you have a large memory usage (e.g. due to a large array or a large map) then, again, you should consider using resizeable standard containers (i.e. containers that can grow to accommodate more elements or a larger map) like `std::vector` and `std::map`, and not `std::array` (which has size set at compile time).

The reasons for those two rules of thumb are that the resizeable standard containers perform dynamic memory allocation, can resize themselves automatically (when you play by the rules when using them).   Practically, a program can allocate more memory using dynamic memory allocation (which uses what is known, inaccurately, as "heap memory") than by using variables or objects of static or automatic memory duration (which uses what is known, inaccurately, as "stack memory" where there practically is less "stack memory" available to the program than "heap memory").

Given your description, if I was to use a `static` map, I'd change it to be;

```
static std::map<std::string,DMRecSessionObj> mapExpSessData;   // note no pointer here
```

and then use a loop like this to populate it using code (which may, notionally, be in the body of a loop)

```
std::string string key = obtain_string_from_somewhere();
DMRecSessionObj object = read_object_from_somewhere();
mapExpSessData[key] = object;
```

This allows the map to take care of its own dynamic memory allocation.   That way, if you need to manage the content of the map (e.g. remove entries or add entries) you can use operations that `std::map` provides for the purpose.   Those operations, if you use them correctly, will generally clean up memory correctly (e.g. no leak due to you forgetting to release an object you have created manually with operator `new`, when you remove the entry from the map).

The objects `key` and `object` in the above are created automatically, which means they will cease to exist when the scope they are in completes.   Technically, that MAY (not necessarily will) result in there being an additional object while you are populating the map).   I suggest that additional object is insignificant if the map is large.

Note that, as a general rule, a program that needs a collection of 150000 objects (even small ones) can often be rationalised.    If a program has 150000 objects in a map (or any container) then, practically, it often turns out that quite a small number of them are actually used by the program.   It is therefore better to do some design effort to anticipate or estimate what objects actually are needed in memory, and therefore implement a smaller map or vector.  That can involve trade-offs, such as needing to read infrequently used objects from storage rather than having them always in the map - but can significantly reduce memory usage of your program.   And that can significantly improve performance in quite a few settings - such as where your program is running on a machine with limited resources, or is hosted by an operating system that is hosting other programs, and needs to periodically swap executing programs between memory and swap space (on disk) in order to ensure all programs get to run.

Bear in mind that using a `static` variable comes with significant penalties as well.   If you do a search, you will find plenty of explanations of why `static` variables are often best avoided, and what the alternatives are.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic memory allocation for an object occurs only for the members of the object as a POD.

For example, this class

```
class X
{
 int p; 
 int* y;
};
```

has two members, the `p` and `y` and this will be allocated automatically. However, the memory that `y` will eventually point at (if at all) can be anywhere, in stack, in heap, or invalid. It's the class's business to manage its own memory, for which you have no control no matter where you create it.

A STL class like `vector`, manipulates the memory internally so you have the convenience of creating and managing it automatically. This *seems* that the class entire memory is automatically allocated, but it's not. But the implementation will create the memory at the best location, which is (99,999999%) the heap.

Some implementations keep a static allocation for low sizes (for example, std::string might have a char[5] to save an allocation when the string is only 4 bytes long). But you don't care.